# About the rails way relation models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, models

### Context:

I have two tables, `challenges` and `challenge_steps`. Both tables need to have relation between them, I need to be able to reference a `Step` with a `Challenge` and the inverse relationship.

A `challenge` can have multiple `steps` but ONLY ONE `current_step`.

Schema:

`Challenge`:

```
t.string   "name"
t.string   "subtitle"
t.text     "brief",                     null: false
t.integer  "min_team_size", default: 2, null: false
t.integer  "max_team_size", default: 5, null: false
t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
```

`Challenge::Step`:

```
t.integer  "challenge_id"
t.string   "name"
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "start_at"
t.datetime "end_at"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
```

To do this I can think of three solutions, but none of them are satisfying:

### Solution One:

`Challenge` Model:

```
  has_many :steps, inverse_of: :challenge, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :current_step, class_name: Challenge::Step
```

`Challenge::Step`:

```
  belongs_to :challenge
  has_one :challenge_relation, class_name: Challenge,
                               foreign_key: :current_step_id, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

As you can see in my `Challenge::Step` model I have a `belongs_to(:challenge)` and the Rails documentation reads:

> For example, it makes more sense to say that a supplier owns an account than that an account owns a supplier.

So the behavior is OK, but the code looks odd.

### Solution Two:

Create a table which contains `challenge_id` and `step_id`. Which will reference each `challenge` and its `current_step`

This one is good but it mean we need the read another table to get the needed info.

### Solution Three:

add in the `Challenge` model:

```
has_many :steps, inverse_of: :challenge, dependent: :destroy do
    def current_step
      proxy_association.owner.steps.where(current_step: true).first
    end
end
```

It returns a collection and the schema doesn't respect the real relation between a Challenge and his step.

What would most efficient and elegant? Could you think of a solution which would have none of these drawbacks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why is `Challenge::Step` a subclass of `Challenge`?

Surely you'd want it to be `Step` on its own? For the purposes of clarity, I will refer to it just as `Step`.

--

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/models/challenge.rb
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :steps
    def current
        steps.where(current: true).order(current: :desc).first 
    end
end

#app/models/step.rb
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | challenge_id | current (datetime) | etc...
   belongs_to :challenge
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
@challenge = Challenge.find params[:id]
# @challenge.steps = collection of steps
# @challenge.current_step = latest current step
```

The idea being that you could save your `current_step` attribute as a date in the `Step` model. This will have the added benefit of giving you the ability to see the historical record of when each step was "current".

--

An alternative would be to make a `current` column in the `Challenge` model:

```
#app/models/challenge.rb
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | name | current | etc
   has_many :steps
   def current_step
      steps.find current
   end
end

#app/models/step.rb
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | challenge_id | name | etc
   belongs_to :challenge
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@challenge = Challenge.find params[:id]
# @challenge.steps = collection of steps
# @challenge.current_step = single instance of step
```

--

Your third solution is by far most elegant, but it assumes the structure you have implemented being correct.

I think you don't have the correct setup to handle the `current_step` attribute; you either need a way to distinguish it in the `Step` model or the `Challenge` model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first solution is 'The Rails Way' of doing what you need.

Maybe the only drawback there is the code readability, in the sense that a Challenge doesn't belong to a current step in literal terms, but I think a comment on the line should be enough, as then, the interface to access it is really meaningful: `challenge.current_step`